# Flutter Release app crash on startup : library "libflutter.so" not found?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-release

There are already lots of questions on StackOverflow regarding this issue.

I have already gone through most of the solutions. In most of the answers, developers are suggesting to add the abiFilters. So, I have added the `abiFilters` like below

```
buildTypes {
         release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            ndk {
                abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
            }
```

### But the problem persists and I am still looking for the solution.

When I build the app bundle then I can notice that in the `release` mode `libflutter.so` file is missing in `x86` folder.
[image]

---

But in the `debug` mode `libflutter.so` file is present as you can see below
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Flutter does not support 32 bit x86. So you will have to remove the x86 support from your app.

More info here: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#what-are-the-supported-target-architectures

Comment: I know that Flutter does not support 32 bit x86. My question is how to fix the issue ? As you can see in my question, I have just specified 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a' in abiFilters. But that is still not working.

Comment: are you trying in debug mode as you have specified ndk for releaseConfig only.

Comment: It is crashing in release mode, so I think the debug mode configuration does not matter here.